# multiple results per line in an sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example table 1

```
colA
5
3
1
```

Example table 2

```
colB
2
6
8
```

My result is something like

```
5    2
5    6
5    8
3    2
etc...
```

I want something like this

```
5      2
3      6
1      8
```

Anyone with experience with sql have any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: What is the order of records in each table you need for result? Do these tables have any ID key field?

Comment: The records have an alphabetic and numeric key that's unique to each record, but not unique on their own.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte1 as (
    Select *,row_number () over () as rnk
    from  "#tmp" 
 ), cte2 as (
    Select *,row_number () over () as rnk1 
   from    "#tmp1" 
 )
 Select  colA,colb
 from   cte1 
   inner join cte2 on (rnk = rnk1);
```

Comment: You may want to use a `FULL JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case the result sets have a different number of rows.